# iPhone toolbar for entire app

Tags: iphone, ios, uitoolbar

I have my app base on `navigationController`. So i set the toolbar visible for some views and for others i didnt calling `setToolbarHidden:NO` or `YES`.
first question, this goes in `viewWillAppear` method ?

Then in my `appDelegate`, I put one item on the toolbar but is not being show.
can someone show me how can I use delegate protocol here so each view know what to do when a item is pressed??

my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    //create itemViewcontroller
    EventosViewController *itemsViewController = [[EventosViewController alloc] init];

    //create UINavigationcontroller, stack only contains itemviewcontroller
    navController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:itemsViewController];
    //navController will retain itemviewcontroller, we can release it
    [itemsViewController release];

    UIBarButtonItem *systemItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                    target:self
                                    action:@selector(pressButton1:)];
    //Use this to put space in between your toolbox buttons
    UIBarButtonItem *flexItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                 initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                 target:nil
                                 action:nil];
    //Add buttons to the array
    NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: systemItem1, flexItem,nil];

    //release buttons
    [systemItem1 release];
    [flexItem release];

    //add array of buttons to toolbar
    [navController.toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];

    //set navController's view in window hierarchy
    [[self window] setRootViewController:navController];
    [navController release];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

thx in advance!

Comment: Is the toolbar not being shown, or just the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

The toolbar us hidden by default. The `toolbarItems` should be stored in the respective view controller, not the navigation controller.

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> **Displaying a Toolbar**
>   In iOS 3.0 and later, navigation controller objects make it easy to provide a custom toolbar for each screen of a
>   navigation interface. The navigation controller object now manages an
>   optional toolbar in its view hierarchy. When displayed, this toolbar
>   obtains its current set of items from the toolbarItems property of the
>   active view controller. When the active view controller changes, the
>   navigation controller updates the toolbar items to match the new view
>   controller, animating the new items into position when appropriate.
>
> The navigation toolbar is hidden by default but you can show it for
>   your navigation interface by calling the setToolbarHidden:animated:
>   method of your navigation controller object. If not all of your view
>   controllers support toolbar items, your delegate object can call this
>   method to toggle the visibility of the toolbar during subsequent push
>   and pop operations.

Comment: so if i have 5 views that want to show the toolbar i have to create and insert * them in all the 5 views, knowing that all the buttons are the same and have the same actions ?

Comment: Yes. Copying them to the next view controller is just one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

you can keep the toolbaritems like this

```
ThemeDetailViewController *themeDetail = [[ThemeDetailViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:themeDetail animated:YES];
themeDetail.toolbarItems = self.parentViewController.toolbarItems;
```