# navigation toolbar with items app wide

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad, storyboard

is it possible to make the navigation controller's toolbar show the same button items in all of my viewcontrollers using the storyboard? 
So far, I have enabled the "Show Toolbar" checkbox in the navigation controller. I have also added one Bar Button Item (item1) to the first view controller. But this bar button disappears when I go to the next view controller. I want that button item to stay there in the toolbar regardless of what view controller is being shown.[image]

Comment: This might be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215791/iphone-toolbar-for-entire-app